# Use an image as map and show present location in image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, location, maps

I am designing a Game which is sort of treasure hunt in ios.[image]

I want use an image as a map of a particular area in a view. And show the user location on the image which i'm using as map, so that the user can proceed further knowing his location.

Is it possible to do ..? if So how can I do it..? **

I have gone through certain resources like MapTiler but not able to get relevant one..?

Kindly help me sort it out..?

Comment: Hi there. This appears to be more of a maths problem than a Swift problem : you would need a way of matching points on the image above to geospatial coordinates, and for that you need to know the elevation of the above image, scale etc. Any reason you don't just want to use MapKit?

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far